# What are some characterizations of the strong and total variation topologies on measures?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

The Wikipedia article on [convergence of measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures) defines three kinds of convergence: total variation, strong, and weak. For weak convergence, a number of equivalent formulations are given, but not for strong or total variation convergence. I have two questions.

1. Are there some equivalent formulations for those notions of convergence too? In particular, is it true that $\mu_n$ strongly converges to $\mu$ iff $E_{\mu_n} f\to E_\mu f$ for ever bounded measurable function $f$? According to an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308249/convergence-of-probability-measures-in-total-variation-and-limits-of-integrals), the left-to-right direction holds if strong convergence is strengthened to total variation convergence.
2. Are there some nice characterizations of these topologies (or even the weak topology) that are not stated in terms of convergent sequences?

Comment: I think for metric that is related, you can check chapter 4 of Le Cam, Asymptotic Methods in Statistical Decision Theory.

Comment: See [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142111/)