Weak convergence of measures and the sup norm
Let $(E,\mathscr{B})$ be a measurable space where $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, compact and convex and $\mathscr{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $E$. Let $\{\mu_n\}_n$ be a sequence of finite measures on $E$, $\sup\limits_n \mu_n(E)<c <\infty$ s.t. $\{\mu_n\}$ converges weakly to the finite atomless measure $\mu$ on $E$. Let $F_n$ and $F$ be the CDF's associated with $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ respectively. My question is, is it true that,
$$\left\lvert \int\limits_Eg_nd\mu_n -\int\limits_Eg_nd\mu\right\rvert\xrightarrow{?}0$$
where $\{g_n\}_n$ is a sequence of functions, $0 \leq g_n \leq 1$ for all $n$.
My attempt:
$$\left\lvert \int\limits_Eg_nd\mu_n -\int\limits_Eg_nd\mu\right\rvert=\left\lvert \int\limits_Eg_nd(\mu_n - \mu)\right\rvert \leq \int\limits_E|g_n|d|\mu_n - \mu|\leq \int\limits_Ed|\mu_n - \mu|$$
My ideas are not even very clear on what $\int\limits_E d|\mu_n-\mu|$ means. But if it is true that $\int\limits_E d|\mu_n-\mu|=\int\limits_{x \in E} d|F_n(x)-F(x)|$, then we have $\int\limits_{x \in E} d|F_n(x)-F(x)| \leq \sup\limits_{x \in E}|F_n(x)-F(x)|$, which tends to zero because $F_n$
s are monotonic, which must converge pointwise to $F$, and the pointwise convergence of monotone functions is uniform.
Edit: I have added more details to the question and my attempt.

I think, $|\mu|$ denotes the total variation of a measure $\mu$. So the question is, simply, does weak convergence of a uniformly bounded sequence of measures (with an atomless limit) imply convergence in the sense of total variation? The answer is no.
Let $E$ be the unit disc $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$. For $r \in (0,1]$ let $S_r = \{(x,y):x^2 + y^2 = r^2\}$ and let $\chi_r$ denote the (unique) rotation invariant probability measure on $S_r$. We consider $\chi_r$ to be a Borel measure on $E$ by setting $\chi_r(E \setminus S_r) = 0$. Finally, let $\mu = \chi_1$ and $\mu_n = \chi_{n/(n+1)}$. It is easy to check that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ weakly, $\mu$ is atomless, but $|\mu - \mu_n|(E) = 2$ for all $n$.

As referenced here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308249/convergence-of-probability-measures-in-total-variation-and-limits-of-integrals, convergence in total variation is equivalent to $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup _{A \in \mathcal{F}}\left|\mu_n(A)-\mu(A)\right| \rightarrow 0$, not $\int_E d\left|\mu_n-\mu\right| \rightarrow 0$. It is therefore stronger than the latter requirement, which I've mentioned in the question. And yes you're right - it's way stronger than weak convergence and therefore not implied by it.

I've added more details to the question and my attempt, in case that's helpful. Thank you so much!

With the new version of the question it depends on what sort of functions $g_n$ you allow. If you consider arbitrary measurable functions, then with the example from my answer consider $g$ to be the characteristic function of the circle $S_1$. Then $\int_{E} g\mathrm{d}\mu_n = 0$ and $\int_E g\mathrm{d}\mu = 1$. Here we don't have the convergence even with the fixed $g$ (i.e. $g_n = g$ for all $n$) @Canine360
